# Android colouring app multiple background images

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating an android studio colouring app and need to have it so that the user can select which image they want to colour. I want it so that they click on an image button on one activity and this changes the background of the next activity that the button takes them to however I have no idea how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to change the color of the next activity on button click of current activity. So, what you can do is:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity2.class);
      //Implement getDesiredColor to get the color according to your logic
      intent.putExtra("color", getDesiredColor());
      mContext.startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

In your second activity's onCreate

```
onCreate(...){
  ...

  View rootLayout = //Initialize root layout here
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  if(intent.hasExtra("color")){
    rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(intent.getExtra("color"));
  }

  ...
}
```

Let me know in case you have any doubts.

**UPDATE**:

With drawable your code will become something like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity2.class);
      //Implement getDesiredDrawable to get the drawable according to your logic
      intent.putExtra("drawable", getDesiredDrawable());
      mContext.startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

In your second activity's onCreate

```
onCreate(...){
  ...

  View rootLayout = //Initialize root layout here
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  if(intent.hasExtra("drawable")){
    rootLayout.setBackground(intent.getExtra("drawable"));
    //Or if you are using ImageView in your root layout to set the background image (I'm using Picasso here):
    //Picasso.with(mContext).load(intent.getExtra("drawable")).into(myBackgroundImageView);
  }

  ...
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

You can have a hashmap mapping each imagebutton with a drawable.

e.g.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> mViewIdToDrawableMap = new HashMap<>();
mViewIdToDrawableMap.put(mImageButton1.getId(), R.drawable.image1);
mViewIdToDrawableMap.put(mImageButton2.getId(), R.drawable.image2);
mViewIdToDrawableMap.put(mImageButton3.getId(), R.drawable.image3);



public int getDesiredDrawable(View view){
    return mViewIdToDrawableMap.get(view.getId());
}
```

How will you call this function:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity2.class);
      //Implement getDesiredDrawable to get the drawable according to your logic
      intent.putExtra("drawable", getDesiredDrawable(view));
      mContext.startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Now, your last question what is rootLayout?

Lets say your activity2 where you want to show this image has somehitng like this as layyout:

```
<RelativeLayout>

  <ImageView
    ...
    android:id="id+/background_imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    ...
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity2's onCreate, do somehting like this (after getting the drawable as I explained earlier):

```
//Here mBackgroundImageView is the background_imageview in your layout
Picasso.with(mContext).load(drawable).into(mBackgroundImageView);
```

Comment: I've used color here, you can use the drawable instead. Updated my answer to use drawable instead.

Comment: Yes i am trying to do it with the drawable, you are explaining exactly what i want to do however am still slightly unsure how to change your code to fit into my project. a few questions, what is button1? Also with the line intent.putExtra("color", getDesiredColor()); i dont quite know what to do here. and i dont get the initialising root layout on the second activity. Sorry and thankyou!

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you out with the drawables. Now, button1 is your "image button". And will update my answer for your question regarding getDesiredDrawable() function.

Comment: I have tried to implement this however I am just getting a lot of errors

Comment: it is not registering my imageButton1, or the put in the hashmap. as well as imageButton1 and view and get desired drawable in the first activity. And in the second it isnt accepting lines View rootLayout or the last rootLayout line

Comment: Hi @Anzeme, you need to modify my code as per your views and ids. I simply provided a way to fix your issue